# Write to AWS SQS queue using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-sqs

Is there any way to stream or write data to Amazon SQS queue from Spark using a library?

There is nothing listed on the [Spark packages](https://spark-packages.org).

What things can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a small library to write a dataframe to SQS

https://github.com/fabiogouw/spark-aws-messaging

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to use [Alpakka's SQS connector](http://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/0.9/sqs.html), which is built on [Akka Streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/index.html).